# @CSRF_exempt not working with new urls?

Tags: django, csrf

I have a working set of html pages that writes and reads from a sqlite table using Django/python. However to clear up some confusion I renamed the url from localhost/sessionsimulator to localhost/session/simulator. When I try to post to the server by calling localhost/sessionsimulator/create everything works fine. When I try to post using the new URL (ie session/simulator/create) I get a csrf error. I have changed all the necessary javascript and url files, but cant figure out why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within the urls file. when calling /session/simulator/create, the server searched for /session/simulator and it was a close enough match so it called just that. adding the $ to the end of all my urls forces the search to be more specific and complete what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are well set the path and in your  settings.py file you are installed:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)

and in your html file you are use the csrf_token validation :

<form method="POST" action=" your view or action ">{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Comment: This is not helpful as I am doing a csrf exempt

Comment: go back to django 1.1 it can be helpful there not with django 1.4 and above